# Overriding TestNG Summary

Tags: java, testing

I do not want the default testNG summary (shown below) to show

```
===============================================
Simple Reporter Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

is there any way that I can override that.

(I know that I can implement my own report by implementing the IReport interface)

Comment: You'll probably attract more people who can help you if you add the Java tag to your question. Also, if you've already tried something include that in your question too.

Comment: I have been reading some source code and looks like the report is being set here https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TextReporter.java   but I have no idea on how to remove this listener at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a lot thru source code it does not seem that this will happen. The only alternative is changing the src code and building testng yourself.